# How to make an API call from one local ionic server to another express local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, observable

So I have two applications running locally; 
one is ionic2 app running on http://localhost:8041 and another one is express app running  on http://localhost:8000.
Now using angular 2 observables when I am making api call with absolute path.
For e.g. From ionic app I making API call to express

```
getComments(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/comment')
    ......

 }
```

This is resulting into calling an API at http://localhost:8041/localhost:8000/comment since it is running on local host 8041 port.

How do I handle this problem using angular 2? Also is there a way I can do a proxy calling so that making API call from ionic something like '/comment' will call localhost:8000/comment?

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly typed the URL? Wouldn't you have forgotten the `http://` (or possibly just one of the `/` or something similar)?

Comment: Yup I typed the correct URL, It was taking base URL from its own domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit `ionic.config.json` file. add your route to api, then restart server `ionic serve`

```
"proxies": [
  {
     "path": "/comment",
     "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:8000/comment"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked and do you know how to handle this in angular 2 without using ionic

Comment: i'm using angular cli, just using full url and the server need enable CORS